# Get NfcTag UID on IOS with react-native-nfc-manager

Tags: reactjs, react-native, core-nfc, react-native-nfc-manager

I'm trying to implement a new functionality to my NFC Scanner App.
It takes the UID of the Tag, the current Apex Session Number and the Date and Hash it and send it out to our Apex Server.

The problem I'm facing is that while under Android I can easily get the NFC Tag UID by

```
NfcManager.setEventListener(NfcEvents.DiscoverTag, tag => {
      tagFound = tag;
      const tagID = tagFound.id; //saves the tagID from the tag object
      /*.......
```

But when trying to access it the same way with iOS I'm only getting 'undefined' or 'null'.

I tried different approaches accessing it, but even when piping out the complete tag object into a JSON I only get the contents of the NDEF Message and not the UID:

```
{
  "uid": null,
  "payload": [
    {
      "type": [
        84
      ],
      "id": [],
      "payload": [
        2,
        101,
        110,
        77,
        67,
        67,
        49,
        48,
        48,
        48,
        48,
        49
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I tried using different libraries, but they're all based on the [react-native-nfc-manager](https://github.com/revtel/react-native-nfc-manager) library.

Comment: Have you found any solution?